# Can we omit </body> and </html>?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Benefits of omitting closing body and html tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297753/benefits-of-omitting-closing-body-and-html-tags)

If you see google.com source html you see there are not `</body>` and `</html>`.

Do you think is it safe to omit them? Well considering google does it I would say yes.

Please take in consideration only `HTML 5`

Comment: See also: [Benefits of omitting closing body and html tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297753/benefits-of-omitting-closing-body-and-html-tags)

Comment: This sounds like a personal decision ;)  The XHTML purists out there may not like it, but I'd wager the majority of browsers would be able to handle it.  I'd not do it though myself (though my sites don't really need to squeeze every last bit of performance/bandwidth/size/etc.)

Comment: A similar question: [HTML: Include, or exclude, optional closing tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags)

The response the most suited to your case: [you never need </body></html>](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3008787/938111)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
```

> This document was successfully checked as HTML5! - http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers will handle it fine. The real question is 'why would you'? Google does all sorts of things in order to get very high throughput at very high speeds, many of which are questionable in terms of standards compliance (for example, they 'cheat' their way out of the limitations of TCP - http://blog.benstrong.com/2010/11/google-and-microsoft-cheat-on-slow.html ). They're competing for hundredths of milliseconds to make things more efficient though. The hundredth of a millisecond spent to send those extra characters might be worth something to them.

If you're *not* building something of the scale of Google though, I'd strongly suggest aiming less for the milliseconds and more for the principle of least astonishment. If developers expect tags to be closed, then close them. You'll waste more effort explaining how browsers still work without those tags then you'll ever save.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are doing. Google probably generates a lot of the code on their page dynamically and doesn't require the tags. However I would stick to W3C standards so more browsers will be able to display your page properly and keep the  and  tags.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the tags are functionally unnecessary (meaning you won't have any problems as a result of leaving them out) but that they would cause your site to fail W3C validation.

Of course, whether validation is strictly necessary is a whole different debate.  At this moment, the Google homepage does not pass validation and reaching the end of the file with open tags is cited as one (among many) reasons.

Check out these similar questions for further discussion:

[Benefits of Omitting Closing Body and HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297753/benefits-of-omitting-closing-body-and-html-tags)

[Is It Necessary to Write Head, Body and HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

As per the reference:

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#a-basic-document

> The html element is the root element of a document. Every document must begin with this element, and it must contain both the head and body elements.

Also, in my case `www.google.com` as of now returns a document that has both `html` and `body` tags.

However, per this document:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/syntax.html#writing

> An html element's start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.
>
> An html element's end tag may be omitted if the html element is not immediately followed by a comment.
>
> A head element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the head element is an element.
>
> A head element's end tag may be omitted if the head element is not immediately followed by a space character or a comment.
>
> A body element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the body element is not a space character or a comment, except if the first thing inside the body element is a script or style element.
>
> A body element's end tag may be omitted if the body element is not immediately followed by a comment.

So, this will validate in http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input (with 3 warnings, though):

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Test</title>
```

Comment: i am not talking about OPENING tags. but CLOSING. `</body>`

Comment: @yes123 Ah, sorry, misunderstood that. Regardless, both are optional as you can see from the last example, so this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but that's not a good idea. 
This will end in validation failures. Especially if you're using an IDE to check your html= code.